# Visio drawing control for visual studio 2019

Tags: wpf, visio

I am working with microsoft visio drawing control 15 in wpf application, which working with visio 2013.
I have noticed to some great runtime performence improvement when working on visio 19 vs visio 13, with my drawings.
I saw that visio 19 has the microsft visio viewer, but it **does not help** me to work with my own visio extension.
Does anyone knows a way to use the drawing control(15) for visio 19 drawing, or any other solution to that does the same with better performance?

Comment: What is "drawing control(15)"?

Comment: The updated visio drawing control according to microsoft is belongs to visio 2013 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/visio/concepts/about-the-visio-drawing-control which is version 15.0